# PickerView и Label

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Добрый день, есть вопросик который не могу решить.

Мне нужно выбрать значение в `PickerView` и нужно что бы при выборе оно отображалось в `Label`. Как это сделать?
Т.е. я кручу пикер оно автоматически отображает выбранный вариант в Лейбле, потом просто кликаю "Ок" и он там остается а сам пикер скрывается .

P.S. Я знаю как `DatePicker` взять, но у простого ничего не получается =(

---

Есть метод

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    NSLog(@"Selected Color: %@. Index of selected color: %i", [array objectAtIndex:row], row);
}
```

Вот и все

Answer (score 1, accepted):

хранить пикер как outlet или привязать функцию, например:

```
- (IBAction)valuePickerChanged:(id)sender {
    [self validateDatePicker];
}

 - (void)validateDatePicker {
    //may becheck data
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [df setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [self.yourLabel setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [df stringFromDate:self.datePicker.date] ]];
}
```